# Spring MVC Multiselect, selected values are not coming back when saving

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, jsp-tags

Can you see what is the reason why the selected values are not coming back when saved?

### JSP

```
<form:select class="multiselect" multiple="true" path="conversionPixels">
        <form:options path="conversionPixels" items="${CONVERSION_PIXELS.getItems()}" itemValue="uniqueCode" itemLabel="displayName" /> 
</form:select>
```

### Controller class for MVC, showing the save method here

```
@Controller
public class EditController extends BaseController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/edit/save.htm")
    public RedirectView save(@ModelAttribute("package") Package package,
        BindingResult bindingResult, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,
        HttpSession session) {

        if (!bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            if(package.getConversionPixels()!=null){
                for (Object o : package.getConversionPixels()) {
                    logger.debug("*****************EditController Save other type "+o.getClass());
                    WadConversionPixels w=  (WadConversionPixels)o;
                    logger.debug("****************** w.getId()"+w.getId());
                    logger.debug("****************** w.getConversionPixel().getId()"+w.getConversionPixel().getId());
                }
            }
        } else {
            ErrorMessageCollector errors = new BindValidateErrorCollector(
                    bindingResult);
            MessageDisplayHelper.addDisplayMessagesToRedirect(errors,
                    redirectAttributes);
            return new RedirectView("/edit/display.htm", true);
        }
    }



    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, new TextPropertyEditor());
    binder.registerCustomEditor(CostMethodLookupItem.class, new LookupItemPropertyEditor(CostMethodLookupTableCode.COST_METHOD, lookupTableService));
    //binder.registerCustomEditor(ConversionPixelsLookupItem.class, new LookupItemPropertyEditor(ConversionPixelsLookupTableCode.CONVERSION_PIXELS, lookupTableService));
    //binder.registerCustomEditor(ConversionPixelsLookupItem.class, new LookupItemPropertyEditor(ConversionPixelLookupTableCode.CONVERSION_PIXEL, lookupTableService));
    binder.setDisallowedFields(new String[] {"conversionPixels"});
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Set.class, "conversionPixels",
        new CustomCollectionEditor(Set.class) {
            protected Object convertElement(Object element) {
                if (element instanceof ConversionPixelsLookupItem) {
                    System.out
                            .println("Converting from ConversionPixelsLookupItem to WadConversionPixels: "
                                    + element);
                    WadConversionPixels wadConPixel = new WadConversionPixels();
                    wadConPixel
                            .setConversionPixel((ConversionPixelsLookupItem) element);
                    return ((ConversionPixelsLookupItem) element)
                            .getUniqueCode();
                }
                if (element instanceof WadConversionPixels) {
                    System.out
                            .println("Converting from WadConversionPixels to WadConversionPixels: "
                                    + element);
                    return element;
                }

                if (element instanceof String) {
                    String lookupCode = (String) element;
                    ConversionPixelsLookupItem item = (ConversionPixelsLookupItem) lookupTableService
                            .readLookupTable(
                                    ConversionPixelsLookupTableCode.CONVERSION_PIXELS)
                            .findLookupItemForCode(lookupCode);
                    WadConversionPixels wadConPixel = new WadConversionPixels();
                    wadConPixel.setConversionPixel(item);
                    System.out.println("Looking up staff for id "
                            + lookupCode + ": " + item);
                    return (String) element;// wadConPixel;
                }
                System.out.println("Don't know what to do with: "
                        + element);
                return null;
            }

        });
    }
}
```

### Model Classes, total three classes are showed for your reference

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Ad_Packages")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "Package_id_seq", sequenceName = "AD_PACKAGE_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
public class Package extends TransactionalEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "Package_id_seq")
    @Column(name = "Ad_Package_ID")
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "package", orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<WadConversionPixels> conversionPixels;

    public Set<WadConversionPixels> getConversionPixels() {
        return conversionPixels;
    }

    public void setConversionPixels(Set<WadConversionPixels> conversionPixels) {
        this.conversionPixels = conversionPixels;
    }

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "Ad_Package_Actions")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "wad_package_action_id_seq", sequenceName = "AD_PACKAGE_ACTION_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
public class WadConversionPixels  {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "wad_package_action_id_seq")
    @Column(name = "AD_PACKAGE_ACTION_ID")
    private Integer id; 

    @JoinColumn(name = "AD_PACKAGE_ID", referencedColumnName = "AD_PACKAGE_ID")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false )
    private Package package;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CONVERSION_PIXEL_ID", nullable = false)
    private ConversionPixelsLookupItem conversionPixel;

    public Package getPackage() {
        return package;
    }

    public void setPackage(Package package) {
        this.package = package;
    }

    public ConversionPixelsLookupItem getConversionPixel() {
        return conversionPixel;
    }

    public void setConversionPixel(ConversionPixelsLookupItem conversionPixel) {
        this.conversionPixel = conversionPixel;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    }


@Entity
@Table(name = "PIXELS")
public class ConversionPixelsLookupItem implements LookupItem {

    public ConversionPixelsLookupItem() {};

    public ConversionPixelsLookupItem(String uniqueCode, String displayName) {
        this.uniqueCode = uniqueCode;
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Id
    @Column(name = "CONVERSION_PIXEL_ID")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="CONVERSION_PIXEL_DESCRIPTION", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String uniqueCode;

    @Column(name="CONVERSION_PIXEL_DESCRIPTION", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String displayName;

    @Type(type = "yes_no")
    @Column(name = "IS_ACTIVE")
    private boolean active;

    @Column(name = "Product_Line_Code")
    private String prodLine;


    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getProdLine() {
        return prodLine;
    }

    public void setProdLine(String prodLine) {
        this.prodLine = prodLine;
    }

    public String getUniqueCode() {
        return uniqueCode;
    }

    public void setUniqueCode(String uniqueCode) {
        this.uniqueCode = uniqueCode;
    }

    public String getDisplayName() {
        return displayName;
    }

    public void setDisplayName(String displayName) {
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a conversion service and set it up to work with MVC by using:

```
 <annotation-driven validator="validator" conversionService = "conversionService" />
```

See section 7.5 here for the conversion class:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html

Edited:

For more info, see the link - section 7.5 - here is an excerpt:

*The SPI to implement type conversion logic is simple and strongly typed:*

```
package org.springframework.core.convert.converter;

public interface Converter<S, T> {

    T convert(S source);

}
```

*To create your own Converter, simply implement the interface above. Parameterize S as the type you are converting from, and T as the type you are converting to. For each call to convert(S), the source argument is guaranteed to be NOT null. Your Converter may throw any Exception if conversion fails. An IllegalArgumentException should be thrown to report an invalid source value. Take care to ensure your Converter implementation is thread-safe.
Several converter implementations are provided in the core.convert.support package as a convenience. These include converters from Strings to Numbers and other common types. Consider StringToInteger as an example Converter implementation:*

```
package org.springframework.core.convert.support;

    final class StringToInteger implements Converter<String, Integer> {

        public Integer convert(String source) {
            return Integer.valueOf(source);
        }

    }
```

Comment: I already have conversion service in initBinder? can you give me more details?